# Can a view, loosely speaking, be considered a type of subquery?

Tags: sql, database

I know that the main difference between a view and a subquery is that the former is saved as part of your database metadata and can later be used completely on its own as some sort of virtual table:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT employee_firstname,
           employee_lastname,
           employee_salary
    FROM employees;

SELECT * FROM my_view; -- This SELECT statement will list all employees
                       -- along with their salaries, treating my_view as
                       -- its source of data
```

But when we use views as part of larger queries, do you think that it's fair to say that a view, loosely speaking, is nothing more than a saved subquery? I'm asking this question because I've noticed that many times I can easily turn my subqueries into views (which alone can make your SQL code more readable) and have the exact same effect.

Comment: Not only a saved subquery, but a saved subquery you can not change - i.e. if someone creates a view where the columns are restricted and you can only access the view instead of the source database, you have only access to the restricted data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's simply not a programming question.

Comment: What's the point of the question?  In many ways a view acts like a subquery, and may generate the same plan as a subquery, but that may be too narrow of a description.  If there's a reason you're asking it may elicit a more appropriate answer.  If you're just curious then the question is both too broad and opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually depends, if it is a regular `view`, then yes it would be safe to say it works as a sub-query when you select from it. If it is a `materialized view` then, while it is still vaguely similar in principle, the execution is a bit different. A `materialized view` periodically stores the executed result set to the disk resulting in a form of temporary result table. In this situation it would operate more like an actual table than a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `SELECT * FROM my_view;`, it actually does that select on the database, bringing all the tables. It's kind of a hyperlink to the select on which you created your view.